# When creating new class with its own method in R, why doesn't it autoprint when entering just the object name?

Tags: r, r-s3

I'm trying to build my first ever R package. I started with a simple project that takes a date and "humanizes" it into the format "X [time unit] ago" (e.g., "3 days ago", "4 years ago" etc).

I wanted the result to have its own print method, so the value has a new class, and I defined a print.classname function.

When I run my new function and enter `print(object)` is works as expected. But when I just enter `object`, nothing shows. What might be causing this? Here's a shortened version of the function and the method:

```
humanize.now <- function(t) {
  now<-Sys.time()
  timediff<-diff(c(as.POSIXct(t), now))
  answer<-as.numeric(timediff)
  attributes(answer)<- list(unit=attributes(timediff)$units)
  answer<-trunc(answer)
  class(answer)<- "humanize"
  return(answer)
}

print.humanize <- function(h) {
  text<-paste0(h," ",attributes(h)$unit," ago")
  text
}
```

(Update: edited the humanize.now function since my abbreviation of it introduced a mistake. Now the resulting object should be of class "humanize")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your `print.humanize()` function doesn't print the value. If you add a line that prints `text` and returns it invisibly it should work:

```
print.humanize <- function(h) {
  text <- paste0(h, " ", attributes(h)$unit, " ago")
  print(text)
  invisible(text)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I found that replacing the `return(answer)` in the `humanize.now()` function gave me the desired response. I think the two are interchangeable. I guess the mistake was that I wasn't explicitly calling on `print()` anywhere? Not sure...

Comment: Please take a look at the code of other print methods in R: `print.data.frame` `print.Date` `print.table` etc. All of them print data and return it invisibly. So likely its a good template to follow.

Comment: Right you are. Just realized my solution created char objects instead of my intended ones.